# Pass a Mongoose object thru middleware in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, express

I have set up a basic logger Mongoose DB objects that I want to pass true the middleware and update it/edit it as the app progresses or specific conditions.

Logger middleware.

```
function Logger(req, res, next) {
  Logs.findOne({ip:func.GIP(req)},function (err, log){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!log) { 
        var log = new Logs({ip: func.GIP(req), user: "anonymous"});
            log.attempts = 1;
            log.save();
            next();
    }
    if (log.attempts > config.attempts) {
        return res.status(403).send({ 
            success: false 
        });
    }
    if (log.attempts <= config.attempts){
        log.attempts += 1;
        log.save();
        next();
    } 
  });
}
```

My example Route.

```
app.post("/example", Logger, function(req,res) {
    if(!condition){ 
        log.attempts = 0;
        log.save();
    }
});
```

How would I have access to the `log.save()` objects as demonstrated above without running `Logs.findOne({ip:f...` function again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `log` variable to your `req` object:

```
function Logger(req, res, next) {
  Logs.findOne({ip:func.GIP(req)},function (err, log){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!log) { 
        var log = new Logs({ip: func.GIP(req), user: "anonymous"});
            log.attempts = 1;
            log.save();
            req.log = log;
            next();
    }
    if (log.attempts > config.attempts) {
        return res.status(403).send({ 
            success: false 
        });
    }
    if (log.attempts <= config.attempts){
        log.attempts += 1;
        log.save();
        req.log = log;
        next();
    } 
  });
}
```

This way you can access it like this:

```
app.post("/example", Logger, function(req,res) {
    if(!condition){ 
        req.log.attempts = 0;
        req.log.save();
    }
});
```